# Homebrew gives transfer closed with ... bytes remaining to read while I can manually download it. How do I do?

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I'm trying to install MySQL-5.7 with homebrew on my Mac.

Firstly, I tried

```
brew install mysql@5.7
```

and I got

```
==> Downloading https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-boost-5.7.37.tar
                                                                           1.3%
curl: (18) transfer closed with 52272168 bytes remaining to read
Error: mysql@5.7: Failed to download resource "mysql@5.7"
Download failed: https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-boost-5.7.37.tar.gz
```

I don't know why is that though, I managed to download the tar file manually

```
wget https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-boost-5.7.37.tar.gz
```

And then I tried both of these

```
brew install -f mysql-boost-5.7.37.tar.gz
brew install mysql@5.7 -f mysql-boost-5.7.37.tar.gz
brew install mysql@5.7.37 -f mysql-boost-5.7.37.tar.gz
```

none of them worked. What else I could try?